# How can I produce a PDF from a XML String using Pandoc Haskell library?

Tags: xml, haskell, pdf, pandoc

Starting from the following XML formatted string:

**Input:**

```hs
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <ul id=\"a8_boYDC\">\n      <li id=\"rp\">\n        <p>\"Alpha\"</p>\n        <ul>\n          <li id=\"cT\">\n            <p>\"Beta\"</p>\n            <ul>\n              <li id=\"wy\">\n                <p>\"Gamma\"</p>\n              </li>\n              <li id=\"Be\">\n                <p>\"Delta\"</p>\n              </li>\n              <li id=\"Ep\">\n                <p>\"Epsilon\"</p>\n              </li>\n            </ul>\n          </li>\n          <li id=\"Ko\">\n            <p>\"Zeta\"</p>\n            <ul>\n              <li id=\"AI\">\n                <p>\"Eta\"</p>\n              </li>\n            </ul>\n          </li>\n          <li id=\"kw\">\n            <p>\"Theta\"</p>\n            <ul>\n              <li id=\"sx\">\n                <p>\"Iota\"</p>\n              </li>\n              <li id=\"82\">\n                <p>\"Kappa\"</p>\n              </li>\n              <li id=\"o_\">\n                <p>\"Lambda\"</p>\n              </li>\n            </ul>\n          </li>\n        </ul>\n      </li>\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
```

**Output:**

A PDF file.

I am using the functions

```hs
makePDF :: (PandocMonad m, MonadIO m, MonadMask m) => String -> [String] -> (WriterOptions -> Pandoc -> m Text) -> WriterOptions -> Pandoc -> m (Either ByteString ByteString)
```

from `Text.Pandoc.PDF`, and

```hs
readHtml :: (PandocMonad m, ToSources a) => ReaderOptions -> a -> m Pandoc
```

from `Text.Pandoc.Readers`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.Encoding
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Data.Tree
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.PDF
import Text.Pandoc.Shared
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Catch

xmlString :: T.Text
xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <ul id=\"a8_boYDC\">\n      <li id=\"rp\">\n        <p>\"Alpha\"</p>\n        <ul>\n          <li id=\"cT\">\n            <p>\"Beta\"</p>\n            <ul>\n              <li id=\"wy\">\n                <p>\"Gamma\"</p>\n              </li>\n              <li id=\"Be\">\n                <p>\"Delta\"</p>\n              </li>\n              <li id=\"Ep\">\n                <p>\"Epsilon\"</p>\n              </li>\n            </ul>\n          </li>\n          <li id=\"Ko\">\n            <p>\"Zeta\"</p>\n            <ul>\n              <li id=\"AI\">\n                <p>\"Eta\"</p>\n              </li>\n            </ul>\n          </li>\n          <li id=\"kw\">\n            <p>\"Theta\"</p>\n            <ul>\n              <li id=\"sx\">\n                <p>\"Iota\"</p>\n              </li>\n              <li id=\"82\">\n                <p>\"Kappa\"</p>\n              </li>\n              <li id=\"o_\">\n                <p>\"Lambda\"</p>\n              </li>\n            </ul>\n          </li>\n        </ul>\n      </li>\n    </ul>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"

export :: (PandocMonad m, MonadIO m, MonadMask m) => Pandoc -> m (Either BL.ByteString BL.ByteString)
export = makePDF "pdflatex" [] writeMarkdown def

f :: T.Text -> PandocIO Pandoc
f = liftIO . (handleError <=< runIO) . g

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mybytes <- runIO $ do
    doc <- g xmlString
    export doc
  lr <- handleError mybytes 
  case lr of (Right b) -> BL.writeFile "output.pdf" b
             (Left  x) -> BL.putStr x
```

**The issue is:**

> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>
> Type H <return> for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.1 -

How can I solve this issue ?

*System specs:
Macbook Air M1
macOS Ventura 13.1
Installed `pdflatex` as the pdf engine.*